# Charset Issue: PHP outputs question marks on page

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

This is how it looks on Firefox and Chrome.

� What is a Premier Listing?

This is how it looks in the netbeans IDE.

```
ï¿½ <a>What is a Premier Listing?</a><br>
```

This is how it looks like in Atom Editor.

```
� <a>What is a Premier Listing?</a><br>
```

I tried changing the charset in the html file and also tried changing it in the PHP side but no effect.

The symbols ï¿½ and � are on the html file itself. My question is 'is there a way to correct this error that we are seeing to the browser show the correct symbols?'

Comment: Can you post your HTML file code?

Comment: This looks like someone tried to paste MS Word content into an HTML editor. This doesn't usually work well. Remove the odd characters, and use proper `<ul>` and `<li>` for bulleted lists.

Comment: This project was acquired by the company Im working for and we are not sure what the original developers did. Cause the project is made of of more than 500 files and any of those files can contain those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because someone copied and pasted those actual characters into the code.  They are not UNICoded that way, or anything like it.  It's actual characters.  Like, someone copied the page in a rendered state when the characters were not rendered properly.

The only fix for this now is to do a search and replace in your code to put the correct characters in place.

I've seen this happen many times when someone pastes text into code directly from Word or something, and they end up with SmartQuotes.  They look fine in the code editor.  Then the page renders, and you get gobblygook.  If you copy and paste that gobblygook into your code, you get hardcoded gobblygook and nothing more.  That is precisely what happened here.

Comment: This is a project Im working on within the company. The project was taken over and no developer here would know the exact characters that was there before.

Comment: You're gonna have to make something up then.  Because I assure you this is not an encoding issue.  It WAS an encoding issue.  Before someone went and hardcoded them that way.

Comment: Yea I assume this is the case after hours of researching.

Comment: I really wish I had better news for you.  This is one of those cases where you're left to sweep up someone else's mistake.  I suggest talking to the client to see if the have some original copy, or if they have an older backup of the pages.